# Spark result size is too big - usecase

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

my input data is stored in Cassandra and I use a table which primary key is by year,month,day,hour as a source for Spark aggregations.
My Spark application does

1. Join two tables
2. Take joined tables and select data by hour
3. Union selected chunks by hour
4. Do aggregations on result Dataset and save to Cassandra

Simplifying

```
val ds1 = spark.read.cassandraFormat(table1, keyspace).load().as[T]
val ds2 = spark.read.cassandraFormat(table2, keyspace).load().as[T]
val dsInput = ds1.join(ds2).coalesce(150)
val dsUnion = for (x <- hours) yield dsInput.select( where hour = x) 
val dsResult = mySparkAggregation( dsUnion.reduce(_.union(_)).coalesce(10) )
dsResult.saveToCassadnra
```

`

The result diagram looks like this (for 3 hours/unions)

[image]

Everything works ok when I do only couple of unions e.g 24 (for one day) but when I started running that Spark job for 1 month (720 unions) than I started getting such an error

> Total size of serialized results of 1126 tasks (1024.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)

The other alarming thing is that the job creates ~100k tasks and one of the stages (the one which caused the error above) contains 74400 tasks and when it processes 1125 it crashes because of maxResultSize. What is more it seems like it has to shuffle data for each hour (union).

I tried to coalesce the number of tasks after union - than it says that the task is too big.

I would be very grateful for any help, suggestions ? I have feeling that I do something wrong.

---

I did some investigation and got some conclusion
Let's say we have two tables

cb.people
CREATE TABLE cb.people (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
)

and
cb.address
CREATE TABLE cb.address (
    people_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
)

with the following data

```
cassandra@cqlsh> select * from cb.people;

 id | name
----+---------
  3 | Mariusz
  2 |  Monica
  1 |    John



cassandra@cqlsh> select * from cb.address;

 people_id | name
-----------+--------
         3 | POLAND
         2 |    USA
         1 |    USA
```

Now I would like to get joined result for id 1 and 2. There are two possible solutions.

1. Union two select for id 1 and 2 from table people and then join with the address table

   ```
   scala> val people =  spark.read.cassandraFormat("people", "cb").load()
   scala>  val usPeople = people.where(col("id") === "1") union people.where(col("id") === "2")
   scala> val address =  spark.read.cassandraFormat("address", "cb").load()
   scala> val joined = usPeople.join(address, address.col("people_id") === usPeople.col("id"))
   ```
2. Join two tables and then union two select for id 1 and 2

   ```
   scala> val peopleAddress = address.join(usPeople, address.col("people_id") === usPeople.col("id"))
   scala> val joined2 = peopleAddress.where(col("id") === "1") union peopleAddress.where(col("id") === "2")
   ```

both return the same result

```
+---------+----+---+------+                                                     
|people_id|name| id|  name|
+---------+----+---+------+
|        1| USA|  1|  John|
|        2| USA|  2|Monica|
+---------+----+---+------+
```

But looking at the explain I can see a big difference

```
scala> joined.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*SortMergeJoin [people_id#10], [id#0], Inner
:- *Sort [people_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(people_id#10, 200)
:     +- *Filter (((people_id#10 = 1) || (people_id#10 = 2)) && isnotnull(people_id#10))
:        +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@3077e4aa [people_id#10,name#11] PushedFilters: [Or(EqualTo(people_id,1),EqualTo(people_id,2)), IsNotNull(people_id)], ReadSchema: struct<people_id:string,name:string>
+- *Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200)
      +- Union
         :- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
         :  +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,1)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
         +- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
            +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,2)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>

scala> joined2.explain
== Physical Plan ==
Union
:- *SortMergeJoin [people_id#10], [id#0], Inner
:  :- *Sort [people_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(people_id#10, 200)
:  :     +- *Filter isnotnull(people_id#10)
:  :        +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@3077e4aa [people_id#10,name#11] PushedFilters: [*EqualTo(people_id,1), IsNotNull(people_id)], ReadSchema: struct<people_id:string,name:string>
:  +- *Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200)
:        +- Union
:           :- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
:           :  +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,1)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
:           +- *Filter (isnotnull(id#0) && (id#0 = 1))
:              +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,2), EqualTo(id,1)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
+- *SortMergeJoin [people_id#10], [id#0], Inner
   :- *Sort [people_id#10 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(people_id#10, 200)
   :     +- *Filter isnotnull(people_id#10)
   :        +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@3077e4aa [people_id#10,name#11] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(people_id), *EqualTo(people_id,2)], ReadSchema: struct<people_id:string,name:string>
   +- *Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200)
         +- Union
            :- *Filter (isnotnull(id#0) && (id#0 = 2))
            :  +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,1), EqualTo(id,2)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
            +- *Filter isnotnull(id#0)
               +- *Scan org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation@6846e4e8 [id#0,name#1] PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), *EqualTo(id,2)], ReadSchema: struct<id:string,name:string>
```

Now it's quite clear for me that what I did was this joined2 version when in the loop for each union there was called join. I though that Spark would be enough smart to reduce that to the first version...

Now current graph looks much more better
[image]

I hope that other people will not make the same mistake I made :) Unfortunately I covered spark with my abstraction level which covers that simple problem so spark-shell helped a lot to model the problem.

Comment: Based on what you included it is not possible to say why data goes to driver at all. What is `mySparkAggregation` and how is it implemented?

Comment: mySparkAggregation it is just a function which does some simple aggregation let say

    `mySparkAggregation(ds: Dataset[X]): Dataset[Y] = {
     ds.groupBy.agg.select
     }`
It seems to me like the join is run within a loop with every union. Since I can see that the stage which causes the error has many tasks which reads the same number of records

Comment: My idea is to reorganize operations in the following way: firstly do union  than join on the result of union and finally run mySparkAggregation on the joined data...